# Doxygen Markdown Links to main page do not work

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I am creating a documentation using Doxygen 1.8.17 which has several overview pages written in Markdown. For this I am creating a main page and a few other pages, which will contain links between each other like shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275887/how-do-i-link-between-markdown-documents-in-doxygen) and in the doxygen documentation.

My problem is, that links from the other pages to the main page (README.md) **don't work**,
while links from the main page to the other pages work and
links between other pages work.

I compiled the example using a defauld doxyfile (`doxygen -g` followed by `doxygen Doxyfile`). 
While compiling, doxygen complains about unresolved references
( `DoxyMinimalExample/otherpage.md:6: warning: unable to resolve reference to 'mainpage' for \ref command`)

No link to README.md works. How do I create a link back to the main page? How is the correct name for the \ref command?

Minimal example (all files in the same folder): README.md

```
# The Main Page {#mainpage}
My Main Page
============

Documentation that will appear on the main page

1. See [the other page](@ref otherpage) for more info.
2. or see @ref md_otherpage for more info.

or
1. See [the third page](@ref thirdpage) for more info.
```

otherpage.md

```
# The Other Page {#otherpage}
My other page
============

More detailed Info
1. See [the main page](@ref mainpage) for an overview.
2. See [the main page](@ref #mainpage) for an overview.
3. See [the main page](@ref #README) for an overview.
4. See [the main page](@ref README) for an overview.
5. See [the main page](@ref README.md) for an overview.
6. See [the main page](README.md) for an overview.
7. See [the main page](@ref md_README) for an overview.
8. See [the main page](@ref md_mainpage) for an overview.
9. See [the main page](md_README) for an overview.
10. See [the main page](md_mainpage) for an overview.
11. See @ref mainpage for an overview.
12. See [the main page](@ref md_README.md) for an overview.
13. See @ref md_README for an overview.
14. See @ref md_README.md for an overview.

or
1. See [the third page](@ref thirdpage) for other info
```

thirdpage.md

```
# The Third Page {#thirdpage}
My third page
============

More detailed Info
1. See [the other page](@ref otherpage) for other info
```

Comment: A bit strange, have to check why, but you can refer to the mainpage by means of "index" so e.g. `See [the main page](@ref index) for an overview.`

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I did not think of that. That solves my usecase but leaves the mystery....

Comment: It is indeed a bit of a mystery, maybe worth to create an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit strange that a page with anchor `{#mainpage}` cannot be referenced in doxygen and one has to use 'index' as reference.

I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 7511, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/7511) to overcome this problem.

EDIT: Code of the pull request has been integrated in master on github