# Markdown and doxygen linking back to a file

Tags: hyperlink, directory, markdown, doxygen

Doxygen now allows to link md files to other md files with regular markdown syntax:
[How do I link between markdown documents in doxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275887/how-do-i-link-between-markdown-documents-in-doxygen)

I have the following file structure:

```
MyDir/README.md
MyDir/Docs/other.md
```

Linking from `README.md` to `other.md` is straigforward:

`[My link](Docs/other.md)`

However linking from other to Readme is not working:

`[My back link](README.md)`

Since doxygen generates its links relative to where it is run, and I am running doxygen on `MyDir`, that should be the correct relative path. I also tried
`[My back link](../README.md)`

Just in case, but no luck.

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use? I tried the current doxygen version (1.8.18) and it looks to me that it is working.

Comment: Seems I am using 1.8.13

Comment: In the master version on github  a fix has been made (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/7790) maybe this is of interest to this question as well.

Comment: I will try it out when it gets merged

Comment: It is already merged.